# How to populate double pointer of size [n,y]

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a C function that allows me to populate a double pointer, but populating a double pointer of dimension [n,y > n] crashes the program.

The program I'm writing needs to multiply two matrices (in the form of double pointers),  which contain random values between 0 and 9 (inclusive). The function responsible for populating the matrices is able to populate, for example, a matrix of 2 rows of 3 elements, but crashes when trying to populate a matrix of 3 rows of 2 element each. I've tried to swap dimension values around in the function, but beyond that, I'm stumped.

In main function:

```
int **Matrix1 = malloc(cols1 * sizeof(int));  //Declare double pointer as matrix to be multiplied [2D]
for (i1=0; i1 < rows1; i1++)
{
    Matrix1[i1] = malloc(rows1 * sizeof(int));
}

int **Matrix2 = malloc(cols2 * sizeof(int));  //Declare double pointer as matrix to be multiplied [2D]
for (i1=0; i1 < rows2; i1++)
{
    Matrix2[i1] = malloc(rows2 * sizeof(int));
}

FillMatrix(&Matrix1, rows1, cols1);     //Function to populate matrices
DisplayMatrix(&Matrix1, rows1, cols1);  //Function to display matrices

FillMatrix(&Matrix2, rows2, cols2);
DisplayMatrix(&Matrix2, rows2, cols2);  //This calling of the function causes the crash
```

Function to populate matrices:

```
void FillMatrix(int ***matrix, int sizeRow, int sizeCol)
{
    int i1, i2;

    for (i1=0; i1 < sizeCol; i1++)  //Loop to step through each row
    {
        for (i2=0; i2 < sizeRow; i2++)  //Loop to step through each element in  a row
        {
            (*matrix)[i1][i2] = rand() % 10;    //Assigns random value to matrix element
        }
    }
}
```

I expect (As an example):

```
Please enter the number of elements in each row of the first matrix: 3
Please enter the number of elements in each column of the first matrix: 2
Please enter the number of elements in each row of the second matrix: 2
Please enter the number of elements in each column of the second matrix: 3
```

to give:

```
1 2 5
9 0 6

3 7
8 5
0 1
```

But it only prints:

```
1 2 5
9 0 6
```

and then crashes.

I'd appreciate any help with this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in this line:

```
int **Matrix1 = malloc(cols1 * sizeof(int));
```

First, the argument of `malloc()` tells the reader you intend to store in it `cols1` integer values (`int`). But later on you store `int *` in the elements of `Matrix`.

You allocate memory for `int` and store `int *` instead. These two types can have different sizes in memory and definitely have different types. The code has undefined behaviour.

You should allocate memory to store `cols1` pointers to integer (`int *`). The argument of `malloc()` should be `cols1 * sizeof(int *)`.

**But wait. There is more!**

[`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) allocates a block of memory of the size it receives as argument. Passing it `n * s` does not guarantee that the memory block it allocates can accommodate `n` objects of size `s`<sup>1</sup>.
Because of [memory alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Alignment) requirements, an object may occupy in memory more space than the sum of the sizes of its members and there may be gaps between consecutive objects of the same type.

**What's the solution?**

The C standard library provides the [`calloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) function to be used to allocate memory for arrays. It receives two arguments (the number of elements and the size of one element) and takes the alignment into account when it computes the amount of memory to allocate.

The code above must be:

```
int **Matrix1 = calloc(cols1, sizeof(int *));
```

The other calls to `malloc()` must be rewritten the same way using `calloc()` and the size of the objects that are to be stored in the memory returned by it (`int *` for `Matrix2`, `int` for `Matrix1[i1]` and `Matrix2[i1]`.

---

<sup>1</sup> The value computed by the [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) operator includes the internal and external paddings. Using `malloc(cols1 * sizeof(T))` to allocate memory for `cols1` objects of type `T` is as safe as using `calloc(cols1, sizeof(T))`.
`calloc()` is preferred though because it tells the reader you allocate memory for an array, not for a single object. As a bonus, it fills the allocated memory with zero, which is a good default value for integral types (and integral types only).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the double pointer to behave like an array, you must allocate at once

`cols * rows * sizeof(int)`

Otherwise you will have a good chance to have non-array areas in the middle of the "array".

This line:

```
(*matrix)[i1][i2] = rand() % 10;
```

has a very good chance to try to access such an empty area and crash your program.

---

Additionally, `calloc()` is "recently" more recommended to be used instead of `malloc()`, if available.

Comment: *`calloc()` is "recently" more recommended*? -- It is the recommended way to allocate arrays since 30 years ago. This is what [`calloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) does, in the first place.

Comment: Well, experience tells us that pretty much "nobody" teaches _calloc()_, and people would be scared to hear that the only allocation function they know (_malloc()_) was already not-recommended at the time they learned about dynamic allocation.